# python regular expression on first occurance

Tags: python, regex

**Working**
I'm using regex to find all the links in a .txt file

```
blahblah'url=:'http://link.com/=tag/blahblah'url=:'http://link2.com/=tag'
```

my regular expression looks like:

```
links = re.findall(r"url=:'http://.+?=tag", source)
```

outcome:

```
url=:'http://link.com/=tag/, url=:'http://link2.com/=tag'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a capturing group around the pattern you want returned:

```
links = re.findall(r"(url=:'http://.+?=tag)", source)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> source = "blahblah'url=:'http://link.com/=tag/blahblah'url=:'http://link2.com/=tag'"
>>> re.findall(r"(url=:'http://.+?=tag)", source)
["url=:'http://link.com/=tag", "url=:'http://link2.com/=tag"]
```